# Can an associated Laguerre polynomial be expressed in terms of a Bessel function of the first kind $J_a$?

Tags: bessel-functions, laguerre-polynomials

I have found that associated Laguerre polynomials can be expressed in terms of spherical Bessel function ($j_n$, $y_n$) but what about in terms of Bessel functions of the first kind ($J_a$)?

The relevant formulas I have found which connect these two include limits and integrals, f.e.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snjUY.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMTS4.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOmLa.png) which denote asymptotic behaviour of associated Laguerre polynomials to the Bessel functions of first kind under some provisions.

Does anyone know a more linear relation?

(The problem is of relevance to atomic hydrogen orbitals and Chladni figures. Such a straightforward linear relation would be a good explanation, I believe, of why some Chlani figures resemble to projections of the said orbitals. Any comment on this one is also welcome).

Comment: Assuming your claim that the associated Laguerre polynomials can be expressed in terms of spherical Bessel functions is true, note that $$j_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}J_{n+1/2}(x),$$ and $$y_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}Y_{n+1/2}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}J_{-n-1/2}(x).$$

Comment: There is the uniform asymptotic expansion for $L_n^{(\alpha)}$ in terms of $J_{\alpha}$ and $J_{\alpha+1}$: http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.15.E19 Perhaps it explains the resemblance you observed.

Comment: projectilemotion this seems a plausible justification. If so, it would only leave to resolve when does the Bessel function of second kind (Y) goes zero or whether the Y can be expressed in terms of the Bessel function of first kind (J)..

Comment: Gary the asymptotic expansion could be an answer - I hoped (rather in a naive way) to find a more linear relation between L and J (a linear relation would appeal to the physical problem described above).

Comment: See 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.E3 and https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7 for your comment to projectilemotion's comment. In general, https://dlmf.nist.gov/10 about Bessel functions.